# SQL Server date time conversion issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is the SQL server query I am using,

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(CONVERT(date, startdate, 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime), 8)) AS NewDate,
    CONCAT(CONVERT(date, '7.8.2018', 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, '3:51:23'), 8)) AS NewDate2,
    CASE
       WHEN CONCAT(CONVERT(date, startdate, 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime), 8)) < CONCAT(CONVERT(date, '7.8.2018', 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, '3:51:23'), 8))  
          THEN '1' 
          ELSE '0' 
    END AS comment
FROM
    [dbo].[LMT2_ServerLicenseUser] 
WHERE
    CONCAT(CONVERT(date, startdate, 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, startTime), 8)) > CONCAT(CONVERT(date, '7.8.2018', 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, '3:51:23'), 8))
```

and the output is shown below in the screenshot:

[image]

I am comparing columns 'NewDate' and 'NewDate2' here and if the condition is true then assigning value in a new column called 'comment' which is showing wrong values.

Please help me to understand where is the issue is it a date time conversions issue or something else.

Comment: That image doesn't exist, however, if you're supplying data, you should really be doing so as `text`. Why are you converting your values to a `varchar` though? Treat your datetimes as what they are a `datetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use to `cast(startdate as datetime) + cast(startTime as datetime)` let the column Convert to `DateTime` Type then compare, becasue you can't compare string `DateTime`format.

```
Select *
    ,CONCAT( CONVERT(date, startdate, 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,startTime),8)) AS NewDate 
    ,CONCAT( CONVERT(date, '7.8.2018', 104), RIGHT(+' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,'3:51:23'),8)) AS NewDate2
    ,case 
        cast(startdate as datetime) + cast(startTime as datetime) >  cast('7.8.2018' as datetime) + cast('3:51:23' as datetime) 
        then '1' 
        else '0' 
        end as comment
from [dbo].[LMT2_ServerLicenseUser]
```